# Evaluating vector distance measures

Tags: python, scipy, nlp, scikit-learn, distance

I am working with vectors of word frequencies and trying out some of the different distance measures available in [Scikit Learns Pairwise Distances](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances.html). I would like to use these distances for clustering and classification.

I usually have a feature matrix of ~ 30,000 x 100. My idea was to choose a distance metric that maximizes the pairwise distances by running pairwise differences over the same dataset with the distance metrics [available in Scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html) (e.g. Euclidean, Cityblock, etc.) and for each metric

- convert distances computed for the dataset to zscores to normalize across metrics
- get the range of these zscores, i.e. the spread of the distances
- use the distance metric that gives me the widest range of distances as it apparently gives me the maximum spread over my dataset and the most variance to work with. (Cf. code below)

My questions:

- Does this approach make sense?
- Are there other evaluation procedures that one should try? I found these papers ([Gavin](http://apcg.uoregon.edu/envchange/reprints/pdfs/Gavin_QR03.pdf), [Aggarwal](https://bib.dbvis.de/uploadedFiles/155.pdf), but they don't apply 100 % here...)

Any help is much appreciated!

My code:

```
matrix=np.random.uniform(0, .1, size=(10,300)) #test data set

scipy_distances=['euclidean', 'minkowski', ...] #these are the distance metrics 

for d in scipy_distances: #iterate over distances
    distmatrix=sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances(matrix, metric=d)
    distzscores = scipy.stats.mstats.zscore(distmatrix, axis=0, ddof=1)
    diststats=basicstatsmaker(distzscores)
    range=np.ptp(distzscores, axis=0)
    print "range of metric", d, np.ptp(range)
```

Comment: This approach will or will not make sense based on what you are trying to achieve. This feature set might work better than others with a set of classification/clustering algorithms. While other features might work well with other algorithms. You need to have an end metric that you are trying to optimize and based on that you can select the best suited features. That end metric is how you will evaluate your features and algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general - this is just a heuristic, which might, or not - work. In particular, it is easy to construct a "dummy metric" which will "win" in your approach even though it is useless. Try out

```
class Dummy_dist:

  def __init__(self):
    self.cheat = True

  def __call__(self, x, y):
    if self.cheat:
      self.cheat = False
      return 1e60
    else:
      return 0

dummy_dist = Dummy_dist()
```

This will give you huuuuge spread (even with z-score normalization). Of course this is a cheating example as this is non determinsitic, but I wanted to show the basic counterexample, and of course given your data one can construct a deterministic analogon.

So what you should do? Your metric should be treated as **hyperparameter** of your process. You should not divide process of generating your clustering/classification into two separate phases: choosing a distance and then learning something; but you should do this jointly, consider your clustering/classification  + distance pairs as a single model, thus instead of working with k-means, you will work with k-means+euclidean, k-means+minkowsky and so on. This is the only statistically supported approach. You cannot construct a method of assessing "general goodness" of the metric, as there is no such object, metric quality can be only assessed in a particular task, which involves fixing every other element (such as a clustering/classification method, particular dataset etc.). Once you perform such wide, exhaustive evaluation, check many such pairs, on many datasets, you might claim that given metric performes best in such range of tasks.